# PHP - Optional JSON field

Tags: php, json

I would like to output a JSON string with an optional fields.

Right now I do it as simple as:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'qwe' => 1,
    'asd' => 2,
    'zxc' => 3
));
```

Now, say, I would like to include/exclude the 'asd' element based on some logic (using an inline if or some function or something else).

I have no idea how to do it, because, AFAIK, there is no such type in PHP that can force json_encode to skip this field - everything returns null or empty fields but does not skip the field itself.

Any ideas someone?

Comment: Generate the array (with or without the optional fields depending on your logic) then at the end, json_encode that array. Basically, if you don't want it in the JSON, don't add it to the array.

Comment: You're unable to manipulate an array? See: [PHP Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp).

Comment: You can update the array within a for loop. You can add or remove fields within the array as needed

Comment: `if(someExpression) $arr['asd'] = 3;` then use `json_encode()` on the built array (`$arr`) ? If you want to check the key exists to change it, use `if(in_array('asd', array_keys($json)) $json['asd'] = 'new val';`

Comment: JSON is a _transport encoding_ for data. If you don’t want something in there, then you should see to it that it does not become part of your actual _data_ in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'qwe' => 1,
        'asd' => 2,
        'zxc' => 3
    ),
    array(
        'qwe' => 4,
        'asd' => '',
        'zxc' => 6
    )
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
    if ($row['asd'] == '') {
        unset($arr[$key]['asd']);
    }
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```